# In the Arcus library how can a single IP address create a Subnet object?

Tags: c#, network-programming, ip-address, subnet, arcus

In [Arcus](https://github.com/sandialabs/arcus) I can create a `Subnet` with a single IP Address:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
var subnet = new Subnet(ipAddress);
```

Since subnets are not arbitrary ranges of IP addresses how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that a `Subnet` is not an arbitrary range of IP addresses. They are in fact a range of length 2<sup>n</sup> starting at a particular position. When provided a single IP address Arcus sets the starting position at the IP and a route prefix equivalent to a subnet of size one. From your question you've created a subnet object with the following attributes:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
var subnet = new Subnet(ipAddress);

Assert.Equal(1, subnet.Length);
Assert.Equal(ipAddress, subnet.Single());
Assert.True(subnet.IsSingleIP);
Assert.Equal("192.168.1.1/32", subnet.ToString());
```